# Log request/response from ElasticSearch Transport client with SpringBoot application

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm using ElasticSearch's Transport Client in my SpringBoot application.
Logback is used as my logging implementation.

Is there a way to enable logging of request/response from ElasticSearch Transport client to help in troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logging the request to Elastic Search doing a toString on SearchRequestBuilder should give you the actual JSON request.
For logging the response doing a toString on SearchResponse should give you the actual JSON response.